# Check if a specific value exists in a specific column in an 2d array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if a product exists in a wishlist array, so I can make a function to get the id of products in the wishlist and the result is

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 42
        )
    )
```

my code is

```
foreach ($products as $product)
    // show products in this style else in this style
```

I want to check if

```
$product['product_id'] = the product id in $wishids array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), see example below:

```
if(in_array($productID, array_column($wishids, 'product_id'))
  echo 'Match found';
else 
  echo 'Match not found';
```

Comment: just change $productID with $product['product_id'] 
its done thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse. You can do it using in_array() function of php.
You can refer it here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

All You need to do is to call this function in a loop traversing through $products and pass the id into the function. You will get your result accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use in_array

```
foreach ($products as $product)
{
if(in_array(product['product_id'] , $wishids)
{ 
  //do something
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!